# SQL query for Moodle SCORM Question Report in Databasetable scorm_scoes_track

Tags: sql, moodle, scorm

Example: 1 user has completed 2 test attempts. The test questions are taken randomly and therefore different questions are stored in the  columns element and value.

[image: table scorm_scoes_track]

How can I count the number of results in column "value" for all occurring questions in same column for the value "SlideX_QuestionY"?

Desired result would be:
[image: result]

```sql
   SELECT
    st.* 
    FROM prefix_scorm_scoes_track    AS st
       JOIN prefix_user              AS u   ON st.userid  = u.id
       JOIN prefix_scorm             AS sc  ON sc.id      = st.scormid
       JOIN prefix_course            AS c   ON c.id       = sc.course
    WHERE   sc.course = 684 and st.scormid = 1195  and st.userid = 9780
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

This includes a join on itself because of the way the scorm values are stored. The join includes a substring which will be slow.

There can also be multiple attempts, so this checks for the last attempt

```
SELECT c.id AS courseid, c.fullname AS coursename,
    s.id AS scormid, s.name AS scormname,
    slide.element,
    slide.value AS slidename,
    SUM(CASE WHEN results.value = 'wrong' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS wrong,
    SUM(CASE WHEN results.value = 'correct' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS correct,
    /* results can have other values so this is just in case */
    SUM(CASE WHEN results.value NOT IN ('correct', 'wrong') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS other
FROM mdl_scorm_scoes_track slide
JOIN mdl_scorm s ON s.id = slide.scormid
JOIN mdl_course c ON c.id = s.course
JOIN mdl_scorm_scoes_track results ON results.userid = slide.userid
    AND results.scormid = slide.scormid
    AND results.scoid = slide.scoid
    AND results.attempt = slide.attempt
    /* A join on a substring will be slow */
    AND results.element = LEFT(slide.element, LENGTH(slide.element)-3) || '.result'
WHERE slide.element LIKE 'cmi.interactions%.id'
AND slide.value LIKE 'Slide%_Question%'
AND EXISTS (
    /* There can be multiple attempts so use the latest attempt only */
    SELECT 1
    FROM mdl_scorm_scoes_track lastattempt
    WHERE lastattempt.userid = slide.userid
    AND lastattempt.scormid = slide.scormid
    HAVING MAX(lastattempt.attempt) = slide.attempt
)
GROUP BY c.id, c.fullname,
   s.id, s.name,
   slide.element,
   slide.value
ORDER BY c.id, c.fullname,
   s.id, s.name,
   slide.element,
   slide.value
```

Comment: Dear Russel, 


Thank you very much for creating this SQL query. It works perfectly. I have learned a lot about SQL queries again and could not have done this on my own.

Hint:
I have shortened the values in the value column in the example for better readability. In the real environment in Moodle the values Scene1_QuestionDraw11_Slide1_FreeFormDragDrop_0_2 0 are stored like this. Therefore, the condition of needs to be changed from

"AND slide.value LIKE 'Slide%_Question%'"

to 

 " AND slide.value LIKE '%Slide%_'" 

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator (free version)